# Selenium having trouble working with Chrome Driver on OSX High Sierra

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

I'm trying to get a simple Selenium exampling going on my MacBook Pro using the Chrome Driver.

My Java code is relatively simple:

```
package foobar;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws MalformedURLException {

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"),DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the Java console:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"E55293B5B5CA0A0B5D8D92156BAC0294","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 149 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'BUBBAs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:81e:75ee:3428:6a72%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/g5/zj52b8jx3yl_699rjb3n5fkh0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.2Fm0pC}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=65.0.3325.181, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 14133de001c084e2d16c0e7772f60e5d
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:364)
        at foorbar.Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

I launched the chrome driver from my console with the following output

```
Bubbas-MacBook-Pro:Downloads bubba$ ./chromedriver 
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 9515
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGVA/AppleGVA-11.3.7/Sources/Slices/Driver/AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 6
```

Now an instance of Chrome does get launched -- see the screenshot below but it has "data:," filled out in the URL textfield.

My OSX uname is:

```
Darwin Bubbas-MacBook-Pro.local 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I've googled but keep coming up short -- any help appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATES:**

1. I am beginning to wonder if I need to allow some setting in OSX's security and privacy arena to allow Chrome Driver to talk to Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a ages old `chromedriver` which backdates to 2014. You need to use the latest `chromedriver` for this

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_mac64.zip

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html